# PHP exec() to compile VB6 from CMD

Tags: php

i'm pretty new to PHP and i need to compile a vb6 project from windows command prompt.
I've tried everythig but nothing seems to work, even creating a batch and execute from PHP code, no way... (the batch works if launched from cmd itself).
I also defined variables with various paths with no success.
i.e.:

```php
$cmd = ('vb6.exe -MAKE D:\Websites\devopservices\dlledit\portaleeditorisen\NewSecurity\Data\NewSecurity_data.vbp D:\Websites\devopservices\dlledit\compiled\test.dll');
echo exec($cmd);
```

or inserting paths with variables:

```php
$proj = 'D:\Websites\devopservices\dlledit\portaleeditorisen\NewSecurity\Data\NewSecurity_data.vbp';
$dll = 'D:\Websites\devopservices\dlledit\compiled\test.dll';
```

here it is the full command i need to execute:

```php
<?php
echo exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" /MAKE D:\Websites\devopservices\dlledit\portaleeditorisen\NewSecurity\Data\NewSecurity_Data.vbp D:\Websites\devopservices\dlledit\compiled\NewSecurity_Data.dll');
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved, it was not a php issue but related to identity in IIS appilcation pool :-)